# The php and mysql work perfectly, but I am getting a WARNING

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to figure this out and have been scouring Stackoverflow and other sites for anything related to my problem.

I have a php script that is updating a mysql table as people open the respective page. The whole thing works fine (as I have been having it print text each step of the way to verify that the data is there. The update is placing either the url and other data into the table if the page has never been visited or updating the total_votes and current_vote per visit. The total_votes is for a statistical reporting used on a different page. The current_vote diminishes in value each week.

For some reason I am getting a Warning. I figure that it is better to ask despite the whole thing working as I hate Warnings and errors that I can't resolve (even if there is no problems with the end result.

The database is set to utf8_general_ci so the url information shouldn't be an issue on that end.

Here is the chunk of code that I have for this section (the Warning is on 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$cururl = curPageURL();
echo $cururl;



require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "SELECT Count(*) as `Counter` FROM `hot_topics` WHERE `article_url` = '". $cururl ."'";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $Count = $row["Counter"];

echo $Count;


if ($Count == 1) {
echo '1';
require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "UPDATE `hot_topics` SET `total_votes` = `total_votes`+1, `current_vote` = `current_vote`+1 WHERE `article_url` = '". $cururl ."'";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

} elseif ($Count == '0') {
echo '2';
$yearHead=$_GET["yearrange"];
$weekHead=$_GET["weekrange"];

if ($weekHead == 'Current') {
$type=$_GET["type"];
$yearHead = date("Y");
$weekHead = date("W");
$Startdate = new DateTime();
$Startdate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead);
$Enddate = new DateTime();
$Enddate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead, 7);

require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO `hot_topics` (`total_votes`, `current_vote`, `article_url`, `article_title`) VALUES ('1', '1', '". $cururl ."', '". $type ." Chart: ". $Startdate->format('d/F/Y') ." - ". $Enddate->format('d/F/Y') ."')";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

} elseif ($weekHead == 'All') {
$type=$_GET["type"];
require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO `hot_topics` (`total_votes`, `current_vote`, `article_url`, `article_title`) VALUES ('1', '1', '". $cururl ."', '". $type ." Chart: All Weeks')";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

} else {
$type=$_GET["type"];
$yearHead=$_GET["yearrange"];
$weekHead=$_GET["weekrange"];
echo $yearHead;
echo $weekHead;
$Startdate = new DateTime();
$Startdate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead);
$Enddate = new DateTime();
$Enddate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead, 7);

require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO `hot_topics` (`total_votes`, `current_vote`, `article_url`, `article_title`) VALUES ('1', '1', '". $cururl ."', '". $type ." Chart: ". $Startdate->format('d/F/Y') ." - ". $Enddate->format('d/F/Y') ."')";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

}
}
}

?>
```

The warning that I have been getting is:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...

Comment: What's the warning message?

Comment: And where is the warning message coming from? Your IDE, the Apache logs, the MySQL logs?

Comment: The warning is:
"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in" Then the path and line

It has been shown on the Internet Browser. I usually test everything on Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer on two different PCs. So the Warning is consistent, but I am not sure why. The process works on all 3 browsers.

Comment: For some reason, `mysqli_query` is returning `TRUE`. [Looking at the documentation](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query), that occurs when a query other than `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE`, or `EXPLAIN` succeeds. You may want to look in to discovering why it considers your query to be something else.

Comment: Your code has an SQL injection vulnerability. Consider what would happen if `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` contained a single quote.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation for the past 6 hours. I actually tried variations of this query that is giving the warning and the warning is consistent. 

I checked it directly on the database and it worked properly. 

My concern is that this little query will be on multiple templates and I have no desire any issues surface when I can't see it.

Comment: Are you sure SELECT Count(*) as `Counter` FROM `hot_topics` WHERE `article_url` = '". $cururl ."'" always returns some data?

Comment: Your query `SELECT Count(*) as Counter...` normally returns only one row, so you should use `mysql_fetch_array` only once. (not in loop)

Comment: icktoofay, I am not sure of an easier solution to the vulnerability save for setting up a process to build the url from the variables. This may be related to the problem, I have the urls being from the masked, not the literal URLS.

Comment: Im ieee, would that cause the warning?

Ankit Pokhrel, I have tested it with over 200 variable combinations and it has returned them 100% accurate so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
   $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$cururl = curPageURL();
echo $cururl;



require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "SELECT Count(*) as `Counter` FROM `hot_topics` WHERE `article_url` = '".   $cururl ."'";
$first_query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($first_query)){
    $Count = $row["Counter"];

echo $Count;


if ($Count == 1) {
echo '1';
require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "UPDATE `hot_topics` SET `total_votes` = `total_votes`+1, `current_vote`     = `current_vote`+1 WHERE `article_url` = '". $cururl ."'";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

} elseif ($Count == '0') {
echo '2';
$yearHead=$_GET["yearrange"];
$weekHead=$_GET["weekrange"];

if ($weekHead == 'Current') {
$type=$_GET["type"];
$yearHead = date("Y");
$weekHead = date("W");
$Startdate = new DateTime();
$Startdate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead);
$Enddate = new DateTime();
$Enddate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead, 7);

require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO `hot_topics` (`total_votes`, `current_vote`, `article_url`, `article_title`) VALUES ('1', '1', '". $cururl ."', '". $type ." Chart: ". $Startdate->format('d/F/Y') ." - ". $Enddate->format('d/F/Y') ."')";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

} elseif ($weekHead == 'All') {
$type=$_GET["type"];
require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO `hot_topics` (`total_votes`, `current_vote`, `article_url`, `article_title`) VALUES ('1', '1', '". $cururl ."', '". $type ." Chart: All Weeks')";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

} else {
$type=$_GET["type"];
$yearHead=$_GET["yearrange"];
$weekHead=$_GET["weekrange"];
echo $yearHead;
echo $weekHead;
$Startdate = new DateTime();
$Startdate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead);
$Enddate = new DateTime();
$Enddate->setISODate($yearHead, $weekHead, 7);

require_once "scripts/connect.php";
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO `hot_topics` (`total_votes`, `current_vote`, `article_url`,    `article_title`) VALUES ('1', '1', '". $cururl ."', '". $type ." Chart: ". $Startdate->format('d/F/Y') ." - ". $Enddate->format('d/F/Y') ."')";
$query = mysqli_query($myconnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

}
}
}

?>
```

if you haven't notice i change the first variable $query to $first_query.. to avoid change in out. the loop get confuse with the repeated use of $query inside the loop.

Comment: That is odd, I have a few conditional queries that make this one look like a walk in the part and never had this warning. That fixed it though, kudos! You Rock Shark!